# RGB to HSV via PIL and colorsys

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, hsv

I have written a function which converts an Image from RGB > HSV. However, when I save the new image the only thing I get is a black image. What should I fix to get it solved?

Any help is kindly appreciated!

My code:

```
def HSVColor(img):
    if isinstance(img,Image):
        r,g,b = img.split()
        Hdat = []
        Sdat = []
        Vdat = [] 
        for rd,gn,bl in zip(r.getdata(),g.getdata(),b.getdata()) :
            h,s,v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(rd/255.,gn/255.,bl/255.)
            Hdat.append(int(h*255.))
            Sdat.append(int(l*255.))
            Vdat.append(int(s*255.))
        r.putdata(Hdat)
        g.putdata(Sdat)
        b.putdata(Vdat)
        return Image.merge('RGB',(r,g,b))
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Once you fix the typos (`Image` should be `Image.Image`, `l*255` should be `s*255` and `s*255` should be `v*255`) it works for me.

Comment: Oh yes!! Mistyping is a consequence of staying up late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't you mix the module `Image` and its class `Image`?

The following code works for me (change the `isinstance(img,Image.Image)` part):

```
import Image, colorsys    

def HSVColor(img):
    if isinstance(img,Image.Image):
        r,g,b = img.split()
        Hdat = []
        Sdat = []
        Vdat = [] 
        for rd,gn,bl in zip(r.getdata(),g.getdata(),b.getdata()) :
            h,s,v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(rd/255.,gn/255.,bl/255.)
            Hdat.append(int(h*255.))
            Sdat.append(int(s*255.))
            Vdat.append(int(v*255.))
        r.putdata(Hdat)
        g.putdata(Sdat)
        b.putdata(Vdat)
        return Image.merge('RGB',(r,g,b))
    else:
        return None

a = Image.open('/tmp/a.jpg')
b = HSVColor(a)
b.save('/tmp/b.jpg')
```

Comment: what is the 'L' in Sdat.append(int(l*255.))

Answer (score 28):

Just FYI, with a recent copy of Pillow, one should probably use

```
def rgb2hsv(image):
    return image.convert('HSV')
```

Comment: True though Image.save() may choke on the result. You'll need to trick Pillow into seeing the channels as RGB by copying them into an RGB Image object

Comment: According to the docs this is not supported: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert

Comment: @whlteXbread The docs just say all possible conversions between RGB, CYMK and L modes are supported. For other conversions, support is limited, e.g. RGB → HSV works whereas L → HSV might not.

Answer (score 4):

i think you are trying to do the impossible, although you can transform rgb to hsv colour (and vice versa) values, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) jpg images can only be stored in rgb or cmyk models.

Comment: I'mm guessing the goal is to get a kind of false color image, not to get a native hsv image.

Comment: @markransom, you can convert colours, but the color model of jpg is rgb. perhaps png or gif might be a better way to go for this use case?