# RGB to HSV Python, change Hue continuously

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, hsv

**What I'm trying to do:** continuously change the *Hue* value of an image, from 0 to 360, saving one image for each Hue.

**How I'm trying:** I started by using code I found on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236956/rgb-to-hsv-via-pil-and-colorsys), then modifying it to change the Hue and save the images.

**What is the problem:** The code from the link above apparently doesn't save the image as true HSV, because when it merges the image it uses the *image mode RGB*. But I can't find a way to make it HSV.

```
def hueChange(img, hue):
    if isinstance(img, Image.Image):
        img.load()
        r, g, b = img.split()
        h_data = []
        s_data = []
        v_data = []

        for rd, gr, bl in zip(r.getdata(), g.getdata(), b.getdata()):
            h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(rd / 255., bl / 255., gr / 255.) 
            h_data.append(int(hue))
            s_data.append(int(s * 255.))
            v_data.append(int(v * 255.))

        r.putdata(h_data)
        g.putdata(s_data)
        b.putdata(v_data)
        return toRGB(Image.merge('RGB',(r,g,b)))
    else:
        return None

# Don't care about the range indices, they are just for testing 
for hue in range(1, 255, 30):
    in_name = '/Users/cgois/Dropbox/Python/fred/fred' + str(hue) + '.jpg'
    img = Image.open(in_name)
    img = hueChange(img, hue)

    out_name = '/Users/cgois/Dropbox/Python/fred/hue/fred_hue' + str(hue) + '.png'
    img.save(out_name)
```

**The last solution I tried:** was to do the conversion as above, and then convert it back to RGB using a similar code to hueChange(...). However, the effect was just that the output images had a *(single)*color overlay on top of them.

Any ideas? Thank you for your time (:

Comment: Just remove the `hue = 0`, `hue += 1` etc. If you use `for` the `hue` variable is changed automatically. Also, fix the indentation on `hueChange`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `colorsys.hsv_to_rgb` to convert the (H,S,V) tuple back to RGB:

```
import os
import colorsys
import Image

def hueChange(img, hue):
    # It's better to raise an exception than silently return None if img is not
    # an Image.
    img.load()
    r, g, b = img.split()
    r_data = []
    g_data = []
    b_data = []

    for rd, gr, bl in zip(r.getdata(), g.getdata(), b.getdata()):
        h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(rd / 255., bl / 255., gr / 255.) 
        rgb = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue/360., s, v)
        rd, gr, bl = [int(x*255.) for x in rgb]
        r_data.append(rd)
        g_data.append(gr)
        b_data.append(bl)

    r.putdata(r_data)
    g.putdata(g_data)
    b.putdata(b_data)
    return Image.merge('RGB',(r,g,b))

filename = 'image.png'
basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
for hue in range(1, 360, 30):
    img2 = hueChange(img, hue)
    out_name = '{}_hue{:03d}.jpg'.format(basename, hue)
    img2.save(out_name)
```

---

Changing the values pixel by pixel can be very slow for large images. For better performance, use NumPy. (The NumPy functions were taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7274986/190597)):

```
import os
import Image
import numpy as np

def rgb_to_hsv(rgb):
    # Translated from source of colorsys.rgb_to_hsv
    # r,g,b should be a numpy arrays with values between 0 and 255
    # rgb_to_hsv returns an array of floats between 0.0 and 1.0.
    rgb = rgb.astype('float')
    hsv = np.zeros_like(rgb)
    # in case an RGBA array was passed, just copy the A channel
    hsv[..., 3:] = rgb[..., 3:]
    r, g, b = rgb[..., 0], rgb[..., 1], rgb[..., 2]
    maxc = np.max(rgb[..., :3], axis=-1)
    minc = np.min(rgb[..., :3], axis=-1)
    hsv[..., 2] = maxc
    mask = maxc != minc
    hsv[mask, 1] = (maxc - minc)[mask] / maxc[mask]
    rc = np.zeros_like(r)
    gc = np.zeros_like(g)
    bc = np.zeros_like(b)
    rc[mask] = (maxc - r)[mask] / (maxc - minc)[mask]
    gc[mask] = (maxc - g)[mask] / (maxc - minc)[mask]
    bc[mask] = (maxc - b)[mask] / (maxc - minc)[mask]
    hsv[..., 0] = np.select(
        [r == maxc, g == maxc], [bc - gc, 2.0 + rc - bc], default=4.0 + gc - rc)
    hsv[..., 0] = (hsv[..., 0] / 6.0) % 1.0
    return hsv

def hsv_to_rgb(hsv):
    # Translated from source of colorsys.hsv_to_rgb
    # h,s should be a numpy arrays with values between 0.0 and 1.0
    # v should be a numpy array with values between 0.0 and 255.0
    # hsv_to_rgb returns an array of uints between 0 and 255.
    rgb = np.empty_like(hsv)
    rgb[..., 3:] = hsv[..., 3:]
    h, s, v = hsv[..., 0], hsv[..., 1], hsv[..., 2]
    i = (h * 6.0).astype('uint8')
    f = (h * 6.0) - i
    p = v * (1.0 - s)
    q = v * (1.0 - s * f)
    t = v * (1.0 - s * (1.0 - f))
    i = i % 6
    conditions = [s == 0.0, i == 1, i == 2, i == 3, i == 4, i == 5]
    rgb[..., 0] = np.select(conditions, [v, q, p, p, t, v], default=v)
    rgb[..., 1] = np.select(conditions, [v, v, v, q, p, p], default=t)
    rgb[..., 2] = np.select(conditions, [v, p, t, v, v, q], default=p)
    return rgb.astype('uint8')

def hueChange(img, hue):
    arr = np.array(img)
    hsv = rgb_to_hsv(arr)
    hsv[..., 0] = hue
    rgb = hsv_to_rgb(hsv)
    return Image.fromarray(rgb, 'RGB')

filename = 'image.png'
basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
for hue in np.linspace(0, 360, 8):
    img2 = hueChange(img, hue/360.)
    out_name = '{}_hue{:03d}.jpg'.format(basename, int(hue))
    img2.save(out_name)
```

---

According to [this page](http://www.clearps.com/photoshop-forum/index.php/t/17204/), 
when the Photoshop "Colorize" box is unchecked, the hue of each pixel is *shifted* by the same amount. 
When the "Colorize" box is checked, the hue of each pixel is *set* to the same amount.

So, to shift the hue by a fixed amount, use:

```
def hueShift(img, amount):
    arr = np.array(img)
    hsv = rgb_to_hsv(arr)
    hsv[..., 0] = (hsv[..., 0]+amount) % 1.0
    rgb = hsv_to_rgb(hsv)
    return Image.fromarray(rgb, 'RGB')

filename = 'without_colorize.jpg'
basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
for amount in (50, 133):
    img2 = hueShift(img, amount/360.)
    out_name = '{}_hue{:+03d}.jpg'.format(basename, int(amount))
    img2.save(out_name)
```

**without_colorize.jpg:**

[image]

**hue+50:**

[image]

**hue+133:**

[image]

Note: When shifting the hue certain region
s of the hair and face became a different color with a distinct, unnatural border. It looks like my code does not faithfully reproduces what Photoshop is doing...

Comment: This works like I tried, but much better code. Thank you. However, this Hue change seems to Colorize the image, like a color overlay on top of it. Is there any way to change Hue without colorizing, like photo editing softwares do?

(edit: What I mean by not colorizing is to do something like a color shifting, pixel by pixel, instead of the color overlay)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Can you give an example? Maybe post or link to some images which show the color change?

Comment: Yes. [This is "with colorizing,"](http://postimg.org/image/fwe9buair/) what the code current does. [This is what I intend to do](http://postimg.org/image/5kctjpiyt/). And [this is what the Photoshop dialog box looks like,](http://postimg.org/image/eaqy4jewd/) with the checkbox that allows me to choose to either colorize or not.

Ps: Thank you very much for the help, especially the numpy part.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the algorithm Photoshop is using to shift hues. My naive attempt, using `hsv[..., 0] = np.clip(hsv[..., 0]+amount, 0, 1.0)` clearly does not come close to the result you posted.

Comment: Ah, I think I found it: The hue is not only shifted by a fixed amount, amounts above 1.0 or below 0.0 are wrapped around (by using the modulus) to fit between 0 and 1.

Comment: Hey thanks for the code. I suppose  just shift hue of HSV would change luminance (bright side become darker and dark side becom darker) according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (-Disadventage part and figure 21. abc). 
Thus I shifted hue but preserved L in LAB thus changing AB only. It looks better to me. 
[+50](https://db.tt/I2gMJeBT) [+133](https://db.tt/yfMHcWcJ)
If you hardly see difference, pay attention to woman's lips or eyes.

Comment: And how would the above code be modified to instead vary saturation and/or value?